# Remove particles with weight paint

Tags: particles, instances

So, I have a Plain Plane with a hair particle system on it. I want to control where my objects are instanced onto it with weight paint. But, when I draw the normal weight paint onto it, it takes all the other particles off of it and paints the particles on in the brush's path. **How can I set the brush settings so that it only takes away the particles where I paint and leaves the rest?**

Comment: Assign all verts to the Density Vertex Group then select the Subtract brush.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!